# How to change the value of variables each iteration after the graph is built?(tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

I want to change the value of the variables manually each iteration but i don't want to change the gradient computation, could anyone tell me how to do?

Comment: For example , if i want to make the value of variables binary in the forward period and make the value of variables back to the original value in the parameter update period.

Comment: why don't you use a `placeholder`?

Comment: The variable I want to change is the weight in the network. I don't think i can use placeholder to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

`sess.run(variable.assign(value))`

Comment: But if the value i want to give the variable is computed based on the variable, using the assign op may change the graph which computes gradients.

Comment: I think it will only change things if the assign op is a dependency of the loss function. Is that the case? Do a series of function calls lead you to the loss function after the assign op?

Comment: For example , if i want to make the value of variables binary in the forward period and make the value of variables back to the original value in the parameter update period. Could you give me some suggestions about this problem?

Comment: Maybe you would have to make some custom op yourself... I'm not convinced my answer won't work. I guess I don't understand your issue. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I have tried your answer but it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for your help.